Can not send USDT on BEP20 chain using Web3 on python
So I wanted to transfer USDT from wallet to another using web3 but I couldnt make it like this! I am using mainnet.
<-- The transaction I get -->

<-- The transaction I want -->

txHash: f75af9c67a0cce7e059889b3d00686a1db860748118822e7dbcc3813f571624e
 tx = usdt_contract.functions.transfer(head_wallet2, amount2).build_transaction({
    'from': user_wallet_address,
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gas': 34515,
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('1', 'gwei')
})


I can't find that hash anywhere, but if input your address to bsc explorer I can find some failures. The only issue seems to be how low the gas is.

https://www.tdly.co/shared/simulation/4b4fb394-aae9-4250-843a-71de8e226fee

Should be at least 51,567, and you are using around 30k
Try 60k and let it use what is needed.

edit (carried over from eth python discord):
There was some confusion as to why a previous transfer used around 35k, almost 20k less.
When first touching storage the cost is higher than subsequent touches.
If the value of the slot changes from 0 to 1 (or any non-zero value), the cost is:
 - 22100 if the storage key wasn't accessed
 - 20000 if it was

If the value of the slot changes from 1 to 2 (or any other non-zero value), the cost is:
 - 5000 if the storage key wasn't accessed 
 - 2900 if it was


thank you bro!!
